# How to decode visualforce view state?

Tags: visualforce

I need to get viewstate values from visual force page. Is there any way to decode the viewstate hidden value in visualforce page.

Thanks,
Prasad

Comment: enable the viewstate tab in dev console : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tab_view_state.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks Vamshi , Is there any way to get values using javascript?

Comment: The viewstate is not designed to be read or tampered with at the client side so the answer is no. If you need extra data values, you have to add them to your page e.g. as hidden fields or for complicated objects as JSON. The client-side JavaScript can then work with those values.

Answer (score 2):

Goto My Setting (beside setup) --> Personnel --> Advance Use detail

[image]

**Check the development mode and Show view state checkbox**

Now open your VF page.. and check all the variable size etc

[image]

Use id in your javascript like .... 
`document.getElementById("com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState").value` to get the values..

You need to use Apex Crypto Class to decode the encrypted data

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class

Comment: Thanks Ratan, I need to get that encrypted hidden value using javascript and decode it and get those values. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Prasad is it stored in cache ?

Comment: it is stored in a hidden value named as "com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState" in the visual force page

Comment: @Prasad Can you pls add a screenshot in your above question with your view state?

Comment: Ratan viewstate is storing as below in the DOM.                                    <input type="hidden" id="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState" name="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState" value="i:yEBwITsIgRvNJxGVkCQMgnDTMTqjoEoOjcEjZRCodWa1qJcGFxzgnUbbBigOe20esr0H0bHywEvKVtq1KCcZdfMqCovMI81H2NafU4sLvRommd........................

Comment: @Prasad then use id in your javascript like .... `document.getElementById("com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState").value`

Comment: Ratan , it is encrypted value. I just need to know is it possible to decode as asp.net viewstate. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34122/discussion-between-ratan-and-prasad).

Comment: I dont think there is easy way ( if not impossible ) do decode the viewstate.